# 3D animated movie about a world falling apart

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

Ages ago, when I was a younger (around 2010-2015), I watched a 3D animated movie where the world was entirely sky (blue with clouds and stuff). It was populated with little planets of varying size where people lived and farmed, and seemed feudal/medieval. I remember the only way to get from A to B was bridges or some other way?

The main plot was something to do with the world falling apart (planets and their buildings disintegrating and floating destroyed through the sky). This blind king/lord met the characters to task them with stopping it at the beginning. By the end, when they had succeeded, he wasn't blind anymore and didn't remember who they were.

The movie has this scrawny leader character, a big strong one, and a weird dog thing (I think it breathed fire?). Somewhere along the way, a girl joined them as well. I remember the leader character berating the strong one at the beginning and saying the dog thing was cooler than him, if that helps.

I think towards the climax, they all had a falling out, and then the most memorable scene of the movie happened when this huge cathedral was falling apart, flying across the sky during a thunderstorm.

I do believe it was a kids' movie.

Edit: The language was English.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  What language was it in?

Comment: The language was English, and I think my dad brought it home on a DVD or we watched it on our network TV box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Dragon Hunters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944834/)*** (2008)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Hunters_(film)):

> *Dragon Hunters* (French: *Chasseurs de dragons*) is a 2008 French-German-Luxembourgish 3D computer-animated adventure action fantasy comedy-drama family film and fantastic tale telling the adventures of two dragon hunters, written by Frédéric Engel-Lenoir, directed by creator Arthur Qwak and Guillaume Ivernel with music by Klaus Badelt and produced by Philippe Delarue and Tilo Seiffert. It features the voices of Vincent Lindon, Patrick Timsit, Marie Drion in the French version and Forest Whitaker, Rob Paulsen and Mary Mouser in the English version. The film was produced by Futurikon, and co-produced by LuxAnimation, Mac Guff Ligne and Trixter. It shares the same creative universe as the *[Dragon Hunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Hunters)* TV series. It was released on March 26, 2008 in France and on March 20, 2008 in Russia and New Zealand. It was also distributed by Icon Productions and Bac Films. The film received a Cristal Award nomination for Best Feature and it earned $12,235,843 on a €12,000,000 budget. *Dragon Hunters* was released on DVD on April 5, 2008 in the United States by Bridge Arch Entertainment, and on November 5, 2008 in France by Warner Home Video.

> **The world has become a vast arrangement of floating islands of varying sizes and shapes. This dizzy universe is populated with rogues, peasants, and petty lords.** Their main concerns are for survival, for this world has become plagued with hungry creatures, who are wreaking havoc, known as dragons.
>
> **Lian-Chu and Gwizdo are two dragon hunters, but they are a long way from being among the best. Lian Chu is a hulking brute with the heart of gold, and Gwizdo is an avaricious, high-strung young man with a talent for scams. Their private dream is to own a farm where they can relax and raise sheep.**
>
> A few floating islands away, there is a fortress owned by Lord Arnold. The lord has a problem. He has been living in fear of the return of World Eater, a monstrous dragon that rises every twenty years to spread terror and destruction. Nobody has been able to conquer him. And nobody has ever returned alive or sane enough to tell the tale. **Lord Arnold's niece Zoe has decided to take matters into her own hands, and she finds Lian-Chu and Gwizdo to help her. She is convinced that they are the heroes of her dreams, and she goes with them to the end of the earth for a fantastic and dangerous adventure.**